# Automatically signing out of other logged in sessions

Tags: facebook, security, session, authentication

In Facebook when you change your password it has the options to automatically sign you out of any other devices logged into the same account. How does this work?

Answer (score 3):

When creating the session, a session key is stored in the database alongside the cookie. This means cookies are validated server-side, with data from the database. Once logged in a user can view the session data retrieved from the database. This gives the user the opportunity to sign out of any other device because once the database entry is removed, the cookie with the same key won't validate anymore.

Comment: If it's that simple why don't other sites do it?